# Am i able to make an instant win game that can't be redone over and over again?

Tags: paypal, instant

also for another part of the question, is it possible to code it where after payment is confirmed, it shows if you win the game? I know you can forward the persons payment to a certain url after payment, But is there anyway to make it where it can't be gotten to unless you've paid for the instant win game: IE: Pay $1 for a chance to win each time: Then they pay, Payment confirmed then  to the page saying "Sorry you don't win, Try again!" and if you win" CONGRATULATIONS YOU WON!" and also i need to make it a low percentage of going to the winning page.

This would work like this:

Click the button
Make payment
(IPN CONFIRMS PAYMENT)
send you to page that only can be seen by paying customers
Gives you a single shown message
MEssage will either be YOU ARE A WINNER or Loser, try again
This page cannot be refreshed or change without a code/payment

But the problem will be me also letting people pay again and again and trying to win again and again.

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow!!! Please always show your effort

Comment: <script language="JavaScript">
<!-- Hide this script from old browsers --

var links = new Array(10) 
links[0] = "veteransofwar.us" 
links[1] = "veteransofwar.us" 
links[2] = "veteransofwar.us" 
links[3] = "veteransofwar.us" 
links[4] = "veteransofwar.us" 
links[5] = "veteransofwar.us" 
links[6] = "veteransofwar.us" 
links[7] = "veteransofwar.us" 
links[8] = "veteransofwar.us" 
links[9] = "google.com" 
function go() { 
var a = 1+Math.round(Math.random()*10) 
var i = a 
location = links[i] 
} 
// -- End Hiding Here -->

</script>

Comment: Above script won't work for my desired end tho I'd rather it never be able to be refreshed, and between 2 links, 1 link 99% of time, other 1% of time. This would be randomly generated would it not be? Also this will not cover my "Must confirm payment"

Comment: I suppose making an IPN Callback page would work, but I don't even know where to start to make one, This all confuses me as I just need to know the basic scripting knowledge of confirming a payment instantly and then making the page that can only be seen once per person. This would make this button work instantly. Meaning....ENTER NOW->Pay->pay confirmed->Win/lose

Comment: Please add the above scenario in the question itself for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish your goal using the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) platform, specifically the [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) and [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) API's.

Comment: That covers part of it :D! Now just to figure out how to make the random message within my site, that can't be refreshed and only accepts the referral of Paypal.com